# Symfony 3 - how to inject the validator into a service?

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I try to inject the validator into my service - but I don't find it:

```
mybundle.service.supplier:
     class: AppBundle\Service\SupplierService
     calls:
        - [setValidator, ['@validator']]
```

the @validator is not the expected RecursiveValidator http://api.symfony.com/3.1/Symfony/Component/Validator/Validator/RecursiveValidator.html - the @validator is an interface.

So how can I inject the validator into my service?

This is what I want:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;


use AppBundle\Entity\Supplier;
use AppBundle\Helper\EntityManagerTrait;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\RecursiveValidator;

/**
 * Class SupplierService
 * @package AppBundle\Service
 */
class SupplierService
{
    use EntityManagerTrait;

   /** @var RecursiveValidator $validator */
    protected $validator;

    /**
     * @return RecursiveValidator
     */
    public function getValidator()
    {
        return $this->validator;
    }

    /**
     * @param RecursiveValidator $validator
     * @return SupplierService
     */
    public function setValidator($validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;

        return $this;
    }


    public function addSupplier($data)
    {
        $supplier = new Supplier();
        $validator = $this->getValidator();
        $errors = $validator->validate($supplier);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> @validator is an interface.

This does not make sense. If it would be an interface, there could not be an instacne of `Validator` service. Yes, it does implement `ValidatorInterface`, but it is not it.

On the other hand, I am sure you would get an instance of `RecursiveValidator`. See my analyses:

- Check the `validator` definition in Symfony's XML:

  ```
  <service id="validator" class="Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface">
      <factory service="validator.builder" method="getValidator" />
  </service>
  ```
- Check the definition of `validator.builder` factory service:

  ```
  <service id="validator.builder" class="Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorBuilderInterface">
      <factory class="Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation" method="createValidatorBuilder" />
      <call method="setConstraintValidatorFactory">
          <argument type="service" id="validator.validator_factory" />
      </call>
      <call method="setTranslator">
          <argument type="service" id="translator" />
      </call>
      <call method="setTranslationDomain">
          <argument>%validator.translation_domain%</argument>
      </call>
  </service>
  ```
- Check the factory `Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation::createValidatorBuilder`. It returns an instance of `ValidatorBuilder`
- Finally, check the `ValidatorBuilder::getValidator()`. It ends with the following:

  ```
  return new RecursiveValidator($contextFactory, $metadataFactory, $validatorFactory, $this->initializers);
  ```

So, you will get the correct instance (`RecursiveValidator`).

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 2):

In symfony 3.4 simply like this worked:

Config:

```
stl.transaction.import.writer.insurance_company:
        class: STL\TransactionBundle\Import\Writer\InsuranceCompanyWriter
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@validator'
```

Your service:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface;
// ...
public function __construct(
        ValidatorInterface $validator,
    ) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }
```